# How to find a particular button/element using both the data-* and value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two dynamically generated buttons:

```
<button type="button" data-btnTyp="btnOP" data-usrRole="3" data-reqID="24" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 75px" value="Start">Start</button>
<button type="button" data-btnTyp="btnOP" data-usrRole="3" data-reqID="24" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 75px" disabled="true" value="Complete">Complete</button>
```

The two buttons have same data-reqID but different values. I am basically trying to find() the button with the data-reqID="24" and value="Complete" and enable the button.
I am very new to JQuery and
I have tried something like this:

```
$("button[data-reqID='" + reqID+ "'][value=Complete]").attr('disabled', 'false');
```

But obviously that's syntactically not correct and hence doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about this: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/ - says this is correct

Comment: What you have works for me https://jsfiddle.net/t3rckv7t/

Comment: @j08691 .. my bad... what i wanted to do was .attr('disabled', 'false'); i.e enable it, since its already disabled. When I alert it it does point to the correct button. So it does answer the question that I have asked and hence up-voting it, but somehow it doesn't enable it. I wonder why!

Comment: You need to use `false`, not `'false'`. Disabled is a Boolean attribute and its mere presence will enable it, regardless of the value. In this case you provided a string instead of a Boolean value, which enabled the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things. If you want to *enable* the button, you need to set disabled to "false". Also, you need to specify an actual Boolean value for the `disabled` attribute. Don't supply a string value of `"true"` of `"false"`.

In other words, it should be"

```
.attr('disabled', false);
```

and NOT:

```
.attr('disabled', 'false');
```

**Full Example:**

```js
var reqID = 24;
$('button[data-reqID="' + reqID+ '"][value="Complete"]').attr('disabled', false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-btnTyp="btnOP" data-usrRole="3" data-reqID="24" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 75px" value="Start">Start</button>
<button type="button" data-btnTyp="btnOP" data-usrRole="3" data-reqID="24" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="width: 75px" disabled="true" value="Complete">Complete</button>
```

Comment: Ahh.. now that's perfect. Setting it as boolean and not as string. That perfectly solves my problem. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 1):

disabled is a property and not an attribute like value or size etc.

It is in the class of other properties like required or readonly and any value you assign to them in HTML/JS is ignored. It is their presence or absence in the tag that matters.

To use properties in Jquery, you have to use .prop rather than .attr

i.e. `$("button[data-reqID='" + reqID+ "'][value=Complete]").prop('disabled', false);` to remove the disabled property

set the second argument to true to add the property.

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference between prop and attr in this case ! +1